# GetStream (Django) - Cannot Enrich Notification Feed

Tags: python, django, getstream-io

I am using the [GetStream Django](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django) package to interact with [getstream.io](http://getstream.io). I have had success using the `Enricher()` class to enrich my activity feed with Django model information for the `feed_manager.get_user_feed()`, but cannot get similar results with `feed_manager.get_notification_feed()`

Here is a shortened version of my model.

```
class Task(models.Model, Activity):
    title = models.CharField()
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @property
    def activity_object_attr(self):
        return self
    @property
    def activity_actor_attr(self):
        return self.assigned_to
    @property
    def activity_notify(self):
        return [feed_manager.get_notification_feed(self.assigned_to.id),]
```

If my view grabs the user feed:

```
enricher = Enrich()
feed = feed_manager.get_user_feed(request.user.id)
# feed = feed_manager.get_notification_feed(request.user.id)
activities = feed.get(limit=25)['results']
enriched_activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
```

My output works as expected, and each of these gets populated with the proper data in my template:

```
Actor: {{ activity.actor }}<br>
Title: {{ activity.title }}<br>
Time: {{ activity.time|timesince }}<br>
```

However, if I switch to the notification feed (note the change in commenting out of lines):

```
enricher = Enrich()
# feed = feed_manager.get_user_feed(request.user.id)
feed = feed_manager.get_notification_feed(request.user.id)
activities = feed.get(limit=25)['results']
enriched_activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
```

Then, the only field I can get data from is `activity.created_at`.

The output of `activity.keys` shows the following:

`[u'activities', u'group', u'activity_count', u'created_at', u'updated_at', u'actor_count', u'verb', u'is_seen', u'id', u'is_read']`

It seems like perhaps for the notification feed, the actor and object are NOT being reported back to GetStream:

[image]

But, it is for the user feed:

[image]

I am stumped as to why. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay ... so I figured out my mistake. I was operating under the assumption all along that the `notification_feed` was a flat feed. Whoops, by bad. It is actually aggregated. Therefore, I was able to make fixes as follows:

Instead of:

```
activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
```

I used:

```
enriched_activities = enricher.enrich_aggregated_activities(activities)
```

Then, in my base template:

```
{% for enriched_activity in enriched_activities %}
    {% render_activity enriched_activity %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which looks in **/activity/aggregated/task.html**

```
{% for activity in enriched_activity.activities %}
    {% render_activity activity %}
{% endfor %}
```

And finally inside **/activity/task.html** I see the output as expected from these items.

```
Actor: {{ activity.actor.first_name }}<br>
Title: {{ activity.object.title }}<br>
Time: {{ activity.time|timesince }}<br>
```

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli system days I have to wait 2 days to mark my own answer as the correct one